# Create new posts in bulk using existing post

Tags: posts

After using short codes and reusable blocks, I have created a post which is created dynamically only on the bases of the title of the post. That post looks like this:
[image]

I want to create 100's of such posts with different post titles like 1) atdhe.net 2) gua.com

I can use the duplicate post plugin but it doesn't create posts in bulk.

My requirement is that the solution should take a list of titles from me as input and then create a post for each of that title while using the post structure of the already published post as shown above in screenshot.